# How do I ensure that any of the threads are not waiting for something indefinitely?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm in process of writing a multi threaded application. Here's my case.

I grab a thousand records from database. Divide it into 5 chunks of list objects. and create 5 threads to process them. I do this same thing every minute until I have records remaining in the database

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessRecords(listRecords))
```

Inside ProcessRecords method, there is a small database update and some send mail takes place. (I'm using System.Net.Mail for email and don't use any ORM for db operation.)

Now I am worried that a thread might not complete because of some unknown issues. What will happen in that situation? Lets say one process (or even more) keeps on waiting for a deadlock in the database or something, what will happen to my application. It will keep on adding new threads with new set of records while some never ending threads. How can I implement something like timeout in this situation?

I want to run this process, terminate it in 5 minutes if it is not able to complete it.

Comment: Can't the [sample code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd537610.aspx) be modified to meet your requirement?

Comment: I don't want to wait for certain minutes (or seconds) before I can start a new thread. Meanwhile I want to shutdown the thread if it does not finish processing in certain number of minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Check out something called a TaskCancellationToken. You can use that to kill the task if you decide (by whatever means you prefer) that it's been running too long.

Alternatively, you could build that into the ProcessRecords() method itself: just have it commit seppuku if it runs too long by having it track its own start time and checking the elapsed time now and then; could be simpler.

That said, if you haven't already given it a shot, you might check to see whether .AsParallel() will save you some headaches here. There are a lot of cases where you can leave your parallelization woes to the compiler entirely.

```
Parallel.ForEach(db.Records, r => ProcessRecord(r));
```

Edit:

```
Parallel.ForEach(db.Records, ProcessRecord);
```

Yes. :)

Further edit:

For the OP, no, the TaskFactory doesn't offer anything like that out of the box. If you want to terminate the process from outside the process, you'll need to roll your own mechanism using some kind of a watcher thread to keep track of which tasks you have running, how long they've been running, and their respective cancellation tokens (or maybe just a bool you have at the top of a while loop...).

Comment: Couldn't `r => ProcessRecord(r)` be replaced with just `ProcessRecord`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Okay, Parallel.ForEach is the way to go. However, my question remains the same. How do I know that there are no threads that are going to keep running, consuming resources without any output?